In Next.js app router, the layout doesn't retain state when next to page
I'm working on a docs website and I have a sidebar on the left that has its own scroll. I initially set the sidebar in layout.tsx to make sure it doesn't rerender but every time we click on a link on the sidebar it rerenders and the scrollbar move back to the top.
If I put layout.tsx one step above then the sidebar doesn't rerender anymore.
In Next.js website it says: "A layout is UI that is shared between multiple routes. On navigation, layouts preserve state, remain interactive, and do not re-render." - On this page So I assumed that this would apply for layouts being next to pages as well not only for deeply nested routes.
https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/thirsty-jones-nh9zlq

Test 1 has the layout next to page - This is what I want but it rerenders everytime.
Test 2 has layout one step above - This works but it will not work for me as I need to use the id of the page in the layout.

I must be doing something wrong but I can't pout my finger on it.

I think I understand what my problem is. In my case the layout is under [id] meaning that if the id change everything underneath changes as well including the layout.
